# Why do I have to clearMemStorage in openCV gesture recognition?

Tags: python, opencv, storage, gesture-recognition

I am trying to create a face detection program using python 2.7.3 and opencv 2.4.3. I have been looking at a lot of code online, and I always see two lines of code that create storage after creating an image, and then the storage is cleared. Why it is necessary to create storage and then clear it?

Here is an example:

```
storage = cvCreateMemStorage(0)
cvClearMemStorage(storage)
```

Here is one of the links I am referencing:
https://geekwentfreak-raviteja.rhcloud.com/2011/02/faceeyehand-detection-using-opencv-python-binding/

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the code you're refering to is using the outdated c api, and the old cv wrapper. please *don't* use that !

prefer the newer cv2 api (together with numpy), the old one will go away in near future.

https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/2.4/samples/python2/facedetect.py

Comment: Thanks, that is good to know. I was kind of confused about that as well. I have seen a lot of variations of code using cv and cv2. Just as a not, an import error is coming up in the code. Does that just have to do with my version of python as well?

Comment: * "Just as a not, an import error is coming up in the code."
  what kind of import error ? (did not understand)
  
* "Does that just have to do with my version of python as well ?"
  probably not. cv2 should work with python26 upwards

Comment: Sorry, I meant *note*. Here is the error- I did not change anything. Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "directory", line 6, in <module>
    from video import create_capture
ImportError: No module named video

Comment: there's no video module in cv2. did you want [cv2.VideoCapture](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#cv2.VideoCapture) ?

Comment: It is saying that "from video import create_capture" is not valid. Therefore, I cannot capture video.